# php doesn't fetch end of array

Tags: php

`foreach` doesn't fetch end of array. I want to use end of that in another method:

```
$array = array(
"Language programings"=>array("php" => 100,"js" => 200),'html'=>12);
 foreach ($array as $kk=>$val1)
   {
     echo $kk.'<br/>';
     foreach ($val1 as $key=>$val2)
      {  
         if (! end(array_keys($array)))
             echo $val2;
      }
      echo end(array_value);//must be show 12
   }
```

Comment: what you actually want to do??

Comment: foreach will always iterate over all of the elements of an array, including the last. that's why it's called forEACH. try a regular for loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try using below code:**

```
$array = array("Language programings"=>array("php" => 100,"js" => 200),'html'=>12);

foreach($array as $key1 => $val1){
    if(is_array($val1)){
        echo $key1.'<br/>';
        foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2){
            if(is_array($val2)){
                foreach($val2 as $k => $v){
                    echo $v.'<br/>';
                }
            } else {
                echo $val2.'<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo end(array_values($array));
```

The result will be:

```
Language programings  
100  
200  
12
```

Comment: thanks, in result of this code html is additional. and not showing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, in your if() statement, you're attempting to see if the pointer is at the end of the array.  Unfortunately, in this case, end() will never be false and so the line echo $val2; won't ever execute.

Try replacing

```
if (! end(array_keys($array)))
```

with

```
if ($key <> end(array_keys($array))
```

also your last line should be:

```
echo end(array_values($array));
```